# Application.kt file for Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use latest FCM using firebase_messaging: ^10.0.1 in my pubspec.yaml

from the documentation in [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview#flutter-android-embedding-v1) , I have to create a Application file in the Android project folder. from that documentation, the code is still in Java, I copy and paste that java code so the Android Studio will convert it automatically to Kotlin , the result is like this

in my `Application.kt`

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService


class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }
}
```

but I have error like this

[image]

I have tried to import, but I will have another error like this:

[image]

it seems that I can't import PluginRegistry and I have error suggestion like this

> Add library 'Gradle: org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3' to
> classpath

but.... I don't understand. what should I do ?
what is the code to be added to Application.kt (Kotlin) so I can use the Firebase Messaging? or should I use the java code in my kotlin project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the right implementation

```
package io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessagingexample

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```